# How to fix unreachability of path in URL ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, react-router, react-router-dom, react-scripts

I am developing an ReactJS app and I want to publish it on AWS S3. I did that and it works if you go to my domain for example i call it [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

My app has different sites and if you click the 'about' button on my website you get redirected to [www.example.com/about](http://www.example.com/about) . This works. If you open a new tab and enter there
[www.example.com/about](http://www.example.com/about) then I get an Error that looks like this:

```xml
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>0HZTJB4DZU234WER</RequestId>
<HostId>AdUx/UR/um/f2XzlTSPT633zZ4+RS/vexQ5asdflkjasdfuwMfxaOMTuasdfasdfX/gDdafdm1=</HostId>
</Error>
```

If I run the react app locally on my computer and go to http://localhost:3000/about everything works.

I think it has something to do with the Routes

my App.js returns this:

```js
return (
        <div className="App">
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<Homepage />} />
                <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
                <Route path="/projects" element={<Projects />} />
                <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
                <Route path="/dataprotection" element={<DataProtection />} />
                <Route path="/imprint" element={<Imprint />} />
                <Route path="*" element={<Notfound />} />
            </Routes>
        </div>
    );
```

I compiled the project with `react-scripts build` and I uploaded the content of the `build` directory to S3.

How to fix this issue? Do I have to use next.js or gatsby or is there a simpler solution?

Comment: What the hosting service/server returns to a client hasn't anything to do with what the returned client code does *after* it is returned. The hosting service/server should be configured to return the root index.html file for all page requests into the app. See the CRA [deployment docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#s3-and-cloudfront) to see what should be configured in the backend service.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using react-snap. Then it works.